# После десериализации класс ScriptableObject не приводиться к классу наследнику

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь реализовать сохранения в игре. Сохраняю значения переменных в классе наследуемом от ScriptableObject

```
public class HealthAndDeathLocaStorage : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float health;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool death;

    public float Health { get => health; set => health = value; }
    public bool Death { get => death; set => death = value; }
}
```

Помещаю экземпляр этого класса в словарь вида `Dictionary<string, ScriptableObject>`. Этот словарь сериализую в Json с помощью библиотеки `Newtonsoft`:

```
public void Save(object saveObject, string fileName)
{
    string strJsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saveObject);

    File.WriteAllText(_filePath + fileName, strJsonData);
}
```

А после десериализации:

```
public Dictionary<string, ScriptableObject> Load(string fileName)
{
    //Чтение из файла
    string strJsonData = File.ReadAllText(_filePath + fileName);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ScriptableObject>>(strJsonData);
}
```

когда получаю объект из словаря и пытаюсь привести его в к типу HealthAndDeathLocaStorage:

```
HealthAndDeathLocaStorage locaStorage = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<HealthAndDeathLocaStorage>();
locaStorage = (HealthAndDeathLocaStorage) SaveLoadAllComponent.Get(this, "healthAndDeath");
```

Получаю ошибку: `Specified cast is not valid`. Это проблема которую нужно решить.

Читал что такая ошибка может возникать из-за отсутствия чего-то у наследника. И до данного варианта реализации сохранений, я использовал служебные функции JsonUtility (но так как JsonUtility словари не сериализует, решил перейти на библиотеку Newtonsoft). При использовании JsonUtility  я делал промежуточный класс в котором определял болванки свойств, которые выдавали исключения, а уже в наследнике переопределял всё как надо.

```
public class StoringLocalData : ScriptableObject
{
    public virtual float Health
    {
        set { throw new ArgumentException("У данного объекта не сущетствует свойства Health"); }
        get { throw new FieldAccessException("У данного объекта не сущетствует свойства Health"); }
    }

    public virtual bool tDeath
    {
        set { throw new ArgumentException("У данного объекта не сущетствует свойства Death"); }
        get { throw new FieldAccessException("У данного объекта не сущетствует свойства Death"); }
    }
}
```

Но

1. Мне этот способ кажется костыльным;
2. В данной реализации вариант с промежуточным классом не сработал.

С текущей библиотекой сериализации, исключения в болванку не зашиваются, при их сериализации эти исключения вызываются и сериализация прерывается. Поэтому промежуточный класс я пробовал сделать таким:

```
public class LocalStorage : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float health;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool death;

    public virtual float Health
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

    public virtual bool Death
    {
        set;
        get;
    }
}
```

И соответственно HealthAndDeathLocaStorage наследовал уже не от ScriptableObject а от LocalStorage. Но это не решает проблему, ошибка `Specified cast is not valid.` не исчезает.

Comment: У вас на этапе десериализации данные могут теряться, если полей health и death нету в ScriptableObject - десериализатор их отбросит.

Comment: @Blackmeser да, в ScriptableObject нет таких полей, это класс встроенный в юнити. До данного варианта реализации сохранений, я использовал другую библиотеку в которой не сериализовывались словари (библиотека юнити из коробки), там я делал промежуточный класс в котором определял болванки свойств, которые выдавали исключения, а у же в наследнике переопределял всё как надо. Но 1. Мне тот способ кажется костыльным (поэтому решил откатить к варианту без промежуточного класса, сейчас перепишу всё поновой и поправлю вопрос) 2. В данном случаи вариант с промежуточным классом не сработал.

Comment: Напишите отдельный класс, в котором будут конкретные объекты с конкретными типами, пусть в нём будет поле типа HealthAndDeathLocaStorage и другие подобные, но не обобщённые в словаре, а конкретные поля к конечными типами. Вот этот класс и сериализуйте/десериализуйте.

Comment: Если вы руками сериализуете объекты, то вам не нужен `SerializedObject`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker и действительно.

Comment: @Blackmeser не знаю насколько верно понял то о чём вы писали, но всё заработало, спасибо:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо  Blackmeser за подсказку.

Как заметил RiotBr3aker: HealthAndDeathLocaStorage не нужно наследовать от ScriptableObject (убираем соответствующее наследование). Создал класс:

```
public class LocalStorage
{
    [SerializeField]
    private HealthAndDeathLocaStorage healthAndDeath;

    public HealthAndDeathLocaStorage HealthAndDeath {  
    get 
    {
        if (healthAndDeath == null)
            healthAndDeath = new HealthAndDeathLocaStorage();

        return healthAndDeath;
    }

    set
    {
        if (healthAndDeath == null)
            healthAndDeath = new HealthAndDeathLocaStorage();

        healthAndDeath = value;
    }
}
```

Сериализуемый словарь соответственно должен быть `Dictionary<string, LocalStorage>`

Значения в экземпляр LocalStorage помещаем

```
locaStorage.HealthAndDeath.Health = currentHealth;
locaStorage.HealthAndDeath.Death = death;
```

Словарь с хранилищами сериализуется и сохраняется методами `Save()` и `Load()`, что я описал в вопросе.